# Member "change log" addon for EE

Tags: add-on, members, control-panel, add-on-development

Is there an equivalent of a Change Log addon to track members actions in the CP for EE?

I'm haven't seen anything like that unless I'm missing some native functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for robust tracking of user actions in the Control Panel than what EE provides, there is [Audit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit) (and [Audit Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit-pro)). Audit adds some additional user tracking beyond what EE does. Here is the list of what it tracks, from its page on Devot:ee

> 1. Member Logins, including Control Panel & front-end
> 2. Member Logouts,
>      including Control Panel & front-end
> 3. New Entries, including
>      Safecracker
> 4. Updates to Entries, via the Publish screen or multiple
>      entries via the Edit screen, including Safecracker
> 5. Deleting Entries
> 6. New Members
> 7. Deleting Members
> 8. Editing of Members
> 9. Changing Templates (editing a template, not its preferences)

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit-pro

Comment: Sorry for the delayed replay to your answer, but this looks by far to be the best addon in this area.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very basic Control Panel log file here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/logs/cp_log.html

It tracks certain actions, though not exactly sure what they are. :) Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, yes that I've seen but wish it wasn't so limited because in terms of entries or content it doesn't log any of that activity.